# R - return value one value in row A based on condition met in row b, sliding window

Tags: r, data.table, time-series, sliding-window

New to coding, and new here as well. I working on an R script, a time series analysis of sorts. The script is intended to detect changes in an average value over time, and based on a trigger (of an increase of 1, or a decrease of 1), return timestamps which direct an individual to where the average started to increase/decrease, and where it reached its highest or lowest relative point. Here is the code that I've written so far (which works well enough for now):

```
#Calculate row averages, adding an "Average" column to the data set
DATAFRAME2 <- DATAFRAME[, .(Average = rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE)), "V1"]

#Calculate NegativeChange and PositiveChange using subscript method (NEW)
NegativeChange <- numeric(nrow(DATAFRAME2))
PositiveChange <- numeric(nrow(DATAFRAME2))
for (i in seq(nrow(DATAFRAME2))) {
  y <- i+1
  x <- i+90
  NegativeChange[i] <- (min(DATAFRAME2[y:x,Average]) - DATAFRAME2[i, Average])
  PositiveChange[i] <- (max(DATAFRAME2[y:x,Average]) - DATAFRAME2[i, Average])
}

#add NegativeChange and PositiveChange data to datatable
DATAFRAME3 <- DATAFRAME2[, .(V1, Average, NegativeChange, PositiveChange)]
```

Which produces this (just a snapshot, the data table is over 4000 rows):

```
    > DATAFRAME3[1:32,]
           V1  Average NegativeChange PositiveChange
 1: 00:00:01| 8.000000    -3.00000000     -2.2500000
 2: 00:00:03| 5.750000    -0.75000000     -0.3088235
 3: 00:00:04| 5.333333    -0.33333333      0.1078431
 4: 00:00:05| 5.230769    -0.23076923      0.2104072
 5: 00:00:06| 5.150000    -0.15000000      0.2911765
 6: 00:00:07| 5.150000    -0.15000000      0.2911765
 7: 00:00:08| 5.150000    -0.15000000      0.2911765
 8: 00:00:10| 5.150000    -0.15000000      0.2911765
 9: 00:00:11| 5.136364    -0.13636364      0.3048128
10: 00:00:12| 5.130435    -0.13043478      0.3107417
11: 00:00:13| 5.125000    -0.12500000      0.3161765
12: 00:00:14| 5.107143    -0.10714286      0.3340336
13: 00:00:15| 5.103448    -0.10344828      0.3377282
....
30: 00:00:36| 5.000000     0.00000000      1.0606061
31: 00:00:38| 5.000000     0.02941176      1.0606061
32: 00:00:39| 5.029412     0.00000000      1.0311943
```

I am having a problem producing the EndTimestamp vector. The code I've written is below:

```
#calculate EndTimestamp 
EndTimestamp <- c()
for (i in seq(nrow(DATAFRAME3))) {
  y <- i+1
  x <- i+90
  if (DATAFRAME3[i,NegativeChange] <= -1) {
    EndTimestamp <- append(EndTimestamp, as.character(DATAFRAME3[Average == min(DATAFRAME3[y:x,Average]), V1]))
  } else {
  EndTimestamp <- append(EndTimestamp, "")
  }
}
EndTimestamp
```

When NegativeChange[i] <= -1, the loop finds the lowest average value in Average[i:i+90], but then returns every single V1 value in the dataset for which the corresponding Average value is equal to the lowest value in Average[i:i+90]. So if its called on line 1 of the datatable above, it finds that min(Average[1:90]) is 5, and then returns V1[30] AND V1[31] (and if there were any other rows in the datatable where Average was 5, it would return those as well). I only want one V1 value to be returned when the condition is met--specifically, one that is within [i:i+90] range.

Any help/direction would be appreciated. I know that there has to be a better/proper way of going about this, but being new to R and coding, I'm not quite sure where to look.

Comment: The R Inferno is a good guide to coding in R and will tell you, for example, that you don't want to grow things in a loop (unlike other programming languages): http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf see chapter 2

Comment: title sounds like a self-join task, didn't go through the question, you should try to make it smaller

Comment: @Frank. Thanks for the link. I rewrote the Negative/PositiveChange code using the subscript method: NegativeChange <- numeric(nrow(DATAFRAME2))
PositiveChange <- numeric(nrow(DATAFRAME2))
for (i in seq(nrow(DATAFRAME2))) {
  y <- i+1
  x <- i+90
  NegativeChange[i] <- (min(DATAFRAME2[y:x,Average]) - DATAFRAME2[i, Average])
  PositiveChange[i] <- (max(DATAFRAME2[y:x,Average]) - DATAFRAME2[i, Average])
}
Can't for the life of me figure out how to do it using the colon operator. The sliding window aspect is tripping me up, I think.

Comment: Feel free to edit it into your question. It's somewhat hard to read in a comment. By the way, in comments, you can use backticks to delineate code and `;` is a valid line-ending symbol in R (so you can use it because newlines won't appear in comments).

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I edited the original post with the new subscript code. As I mentioned above, I can't seem to figure out the colon operator method. Here is what I tried, but I keep getting an error reading "In seq(nrow(DATAFRAME2)) + 1:seq(nrow(DATAFRAME2)) :
  numerical expression has 3461 elements: only the first used" `NegativeChange <- min(DATAFRAME2[seq(nrow(DATAFRAME2))+1:seq(nrow(DATAFRAME2))+90,Average]) - DATAFRAME2[seq(nrow(DATAFRAME2)), Average]`

Comment: Hm, the warning (not an error, I guess) indicates that you have 1:seq(nrow(DATAFRAME2)) somewhere in your code. If you type seq(nrow(DATAFRAME2)), you'll see that it is a vector, but for the colon operator, you must pass a single element at a time. Probably, you meant to use x or y there instead.